# Google SEO crawl budget problem with a website of 2,400,000 URLs: should I keep on serving AMP files?

Tags: seo, googlebot, responsive-webdesign, amp, crawl-budget

I manage a website with 200,000+ products, with 2,400,000 URLs:

- 600,000 URLs for non-AMP visitors in English (per product: 1 page of features, 1 page with photos, 1 page with opinions)
- 600,000 URLs for AMP visitors in English
- 600,000 URLs for non-AMP visitors in French
- 600,000 URLs for AMP visitors in French

I'm experiencing crawl budget issues (thin content, etc.), Google stopped indexing 60% of my total URLs, and I wondered if is it worth serving AMP versions of each page. I suspect I'm wasting the half of my crawl budget with AMP while the non-AMP pages are responsive with a 97/100 in the Google PageSpeed Insights.

Any similar experience is welcome.

Comment: Thin content and 60% indexed are probably not caused by lack of crawl budget.   The fact that Google "stopped" indexing URL indicates that Googlebot did crawl them at one point so that Google could index them before.   Do you have evidence that Googlebot hasn't crawled some of your URLs?  Do you track that from your server logs?    Thin content and de-indexed URLs are usually content and Pagerank problems.  They are very rarely caused by too many URLs for Googlebot to crawl.

Answer (score -1):

Currently Google is giving importance for AMP related pages as one of ranking factor.
But on Tuesday, November 10, 2020 Google announced officially that-
"The change for non-AMP content to become eligible to appear in the mobile Top Stories feature in Search will also roll out in May 2021." in https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/11/timing-for-page-experience.

For now you can keep it. But optimize your non AMP pages for Web Performance since Google is considering it also as one of Ranking factor after May 2021.
So once this update comes may be you can you try this.
But experiment it for section wise and check server log files on how it works.
If its successful you can implement for further sections
Not advisable to remove all AMP pages at one time.

Comment: "Top Stories" is for news websites.   Since the question is about a product website, I don't think this has any relevance.

Comment: Yes but since discussion is about AMP we want to bring in to notice about the Google update. And also just wanted to remind that any changes they are making to AMP version of website may affect traffic